# EC2 - Start a new instance even if executors on the running EC2 are available

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2

I am using the [Jenkins EC2 Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Plugin) to spin up AWS EC2 instances on demand to use as slaves for my build jobs. When I kick off multiple jobs at the same time, I want to run each job on its own EC2 instance.

But the default "Usage" setting is to "**Utilize this slave as much as possible**". This means that Jenkins will not boot a slave for a job unless all the build-executors on the slave currently are in use.

How to configure EC2 plugin to spin up new EC2 instance every time my job is kicked off even not all the executors are in use?

Answer (score 0):

How about just having a single executor per slave ?  Then each build would have to run on a separate slave.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my job is a multijob and it has some downstream jobs which runs in parallel and require some executors, so I cannot set 1 executor per slave.